# Can I set the field CloseDate on Opportunity to null or blank?

Tags: apex, datetime, date, null, closedate

I know that I can use some workaround like that:

opp.CloseDate = Date.valueOf('1900-01-01');

But is there a possibility to have that field not visible for some (cloned) Opportunities? (beyond hiding it on the page layouts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Close Date is related to Forecasting, so it is required by the system in order to make sure your sales are forecasting correctly. Note that the date does not need to be exact; the Close Date is an estimate for when the Opportunity might close. For this reason, the default Close Date is the end of the current Fiscal Quarter.

Answer (score 0):

```java
System.debug(Opportunity.CloseDate.getDescribe().isNillable());

//it returns false => A non-nillable field
```

**isNillable()**

> Returns true if the field is nillable, false otherwise. A nillable field can have empty content. **A non-nillable field must have a value for the object to be created or saved.**

Answering your question: You cannot set `CloseDate` as null/empty. Even if you hide it, there needs to be some value.